# java: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6String8allocateEm

Tags: java, linker, java-native-interface, opencv3.0

When I type

```
java -Djava.library.path="path to opencv lib folder" : "path to my libJavaFileName.so" JavaFileName
```

I receive the following message:

```
java: symbol lookup error: "path to my libJavaFileName.so": undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6String8allocateEm
```

What is the meaning of `undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6String8allocateEm` and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a version mismatch between the Java JNI bindings and your version of opencv.

The undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6String8allocateEm arises because your libJavaFileName.so contains a reference to that symbol but the linker cannot find any object file which defines it.

You can use the program c++filt to unmangle the symbol in to a readable name:

```
> c++filt -n _ZN2cv6String8allocateEm
cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)
```

If you look in the source of opencv 3.1 you can see that this function does indeed exist (its in stl.cpp in the core module).

The symbol is not defined in the libraries for opencv on my machine (version 2.4.8) but it is defined in libopencv_core.so if I build version 3.1 from source.

Therefore I'm guessing its probably the case that you need to install a newer version of opencv.

Its also worth checking that its actually loading the version of the shared library that you think it is. If you do:

```
strace -o log.txt java rest_of_your_command_line
```

Then you can look through log.txt to see which shared libraries are being opened. Try grepping this file for opencv to see if the right version is being loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I have opencv 3.1 which is the latest version.

Comment: OK. I wonder if you have two versions installed and its not finding the new one? I've added a note above about checking which shared library is loading

Answer (score 0):

Your library uses the symbol `cv::String::allocate( unsigned long )`.

You need to load the proper shared object(s) that provide the symbols that your native code depends on.  The best way to do that is to compile your native shared object such that it has dynamic dependencies on those objects by using the proper `-L library_name` option(s).